# writting static methods to copy two dimensional arrays

Tags: java

i am trying to write a static method that makes and returns a copy of a two dimensional array of int passed as a parameter.
 tthis is the code i have written but not sure if its correct

```
public class Array {
     private static int[][] arraycopy;


     public Array(){
         arraycopy =new int[0][0];

     }

     public static int makecopy(int[][]original){
        for(int i=0;i<original.length;i++) {
            arraycopy[i]=original[i];
         for(int j=0;i<original[i].length; j++){
             arraycopy[j]=original[j];
         }
     }
        return arraycopy[i][j];
     }
```

my return also gives me errors saying that i and j are not declared

Answer (score 1):

`return arraycopy[i][j]` doesn't make any sense outside the scope of those `for` loops:  `i` and `j` are only defined within their respective loops.  That's why you're getting the error you're getting.  Lucky for you, you don't need those at that point anyway.

You want to change your return type to `int[][]` and your return statement to just `return arraycopy;`

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer:

i and j exists only in the scope they were declared, meaning the loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<original.length;i++) {
            arraycopy[i]=original[i];
         for(int j=0;i<original[i].length; j++){
             arraycopy[j]=original[j];
         }
     }
```

Fix it by declaring them outside the loops:

```
public static int makecopy(int[][]original){
    int i, j;
    for( i=0;i<original.length;i++) {
        arraycopy[i]=original[i];
     for( j=0;i<original[i].length; j++){
         arraycopy[j]=original[j];
     }
  }
    return arraycopy[i][j];
 }
```

## BUT

1. Your function returns `int`, and not `int[][]`.
2. You have array-out-of-bounds-exception in the return statement.
3. You need to initialize the array to the correct size (it's currently `int[0][0]`).
4. You don't copy each cell in the array,but copying arrays in a wrong way.

A correct approach would be:
(1) remove the declaration of the array outside the method, and the constructor as well (you use static method, why creating objects?)
(2) create the method like this:

```
public static int[][] makecopy(int[][]original){
    int i, j;
    int arraycopy[][] = new int[original.length][original[0].length];
    for( i=0;i<original.length;i++) 
    {
        for( j=0;j<original[i].length; j++)
        {
             arraycopy[i][j] = original[i][j];
        }
    }
    return arraycopy;
 }
```

Take that as first steps.

Comment: at mbyd  how do i initialise the copy array to its correct size i currently have   public static int [][]makeCopy(int[][]original){
     arraycopy=new int[original.length][];